# render :json => results renders as string instead

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have an array of hashes in ruby that I render with `render :json => my_arr`.  However, in my view, i see it as a string, and when I iterate over it with jQuery.each it comprehends one character at a time instead of one element of the array at a time.

In my controller:

```
logger.debug(my_arr) # prints [{"foo1"=>"bar1”},{“foo2”=>”bar2”}]
render :json => my_arr
```

In my view:

```
function query_facebook_for_roommate(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "send_to_my_controller",
        success: function(data){
           //I see data: "[{"foo1"=>"bar1”},{“foo2”=>”bar2”}]" in the chrome debugger
           jQuery.each(data, display_result) 
           //This iterates over each character, eg: [, {, " etc. instead of each element {"foo1"=>"bar"}, {"foo2"=>"bar2"} etc.
    });
}
```

This was working yesterday but for some reason now it's broken. I checked out previous revisions but they're broken now too.  Any idea on how I should debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your return value is not being parsed as JSON. Try this:

```
success: function(data){
  var parsed_data = $.parseJSON( data );
  jQuery.each( parsed_data, display_result );
}
```

or try adding the `dataType` option, set as "json":

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType: 'json'
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I thought render => :json was suppose to send it to the view as json?

Comment: I believe it also depends on the MIME type, so there are places where it can still go wrong.